# Custom j_security_check validation

Tags: jsp, authentication, tomcat, servlets

I have form like this:

```
<form method="POST" name="loginform" action="j_security_check">
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Now my requirement is that I want to do the authentication without using this form. For example, I want to invoke j_security_check and pass the parameters. How it is possible?. Can we do it in that way? How the redirect is handled by j_security_check? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Let us know the use case also, where you want to do this. Coming to your question , yes you can invoke,